# Python: Two-Way ANOVA without specifying columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a large dataframe for work and I'm essentially making a ton of separate dummies so in order to do this easily, I'm trying to create a function. I suspect I'll need to do some ANOVAs but all the [tutorials](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-perform-a-two-way-anova-in-python/) I find require you to specify the columns but I'm looking for a more Pythonic way to do this.

Here's an example df:

```
bookclub = [1, 1, 1, 0]
does_sports = [0, 0, 1, 1]
involved_parents = [1, 1, 0, 0]
pineapple_pizza = [0, 0, 1, 0]
criminal_record = [0, 0, 0, 1]
honor_roll = [1, 1, 0, 0]

data = {'In A Book Club': bookclub, 'Does Sports': does_sports, 'Involved Parents': involved_parents,
        'Likes Pineapple on Pizza': pineapple_pizza, 'Has A Criminal Record': criminal_record, 'Honor Roll': honor_roll}
column_names = ['In A Book Club', 'Does Sports', 'Has Involved Parents', 'Likes Pineapple on Pizza', ' Has A Criminal Record', 'Honor Roll']

#turning it into a df
classroom = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

The df looks like this:
[image]

Next, I'm making a separate df, made entirely of the target column - the honor roll.

```
class_predict = classroom[['Honor Roll']]
class_predict
```

The dummies I'm going to make here is actually not going to be between the already existing columns but rather, when the numbers equal 0 and when it equals 1. To systematically roll this out, I have a function ready.

```
def dummies_func(col):
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(classroom[col])
```

Now here's the issue I'm having trouble with. It's the syntax of the two-way ANOVA. Specifically, the syntax of the model. It's copied and pasted below, with the model line bolded:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
**model = ols('value ~ C(Genotype) + C(years) + C(Genotype):C(years)', data=d_melt).fit()**
anova_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
anova_table
```

Now sure, I can just specify the columns but that's non-Pythonic, and as I've said before, I'm trying to build a function so all I need to add in the argument is the name of the column. I can't think of a good way to do this. The closest thing I can come up with is the iloc function, but even still, I'd have to bring the string to add that in and I get TypeErrors doing so.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. *I can just specify the columns*: could you show what that would look like?

Comment: Well if I manually specify, I believe the syntax would look like model = ols('Honor Roll ~ C(In A Book Club) + C(Does Sports) + C(Involved Parents'), data=classroom).fit()